# Text only input in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Sometimes I am afraid hackers would include scripts in any text field. I may be able to use `sanitize` method, but not for long, because the script is still stored in the database.

For example, in the `input` field, how do I make Rails to accept only plain text? And strips all `<` or `>` or whichever that is dangerous?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

you can `html_escape` it in `before_save` callback for your model

API link: http://apidock.com/rails/ERB/Util/html_escape

Answer (score 0):

I you use Rails 3 then you get the sanitize effect for free when you print the data back in the views.

If you use Rails 2 then you can use the h helper like this to make sure it is correctly escaped:

```
<%=h @model.input_data %>
```

Answer (score 0):

By default in Rails 3.0+, all output is html escaped.

However if you didn't want to pollute your database with html/javascript etc, I'd take advantage of the [before_save callback](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Callbacks.html).

If you are using < Rails 3, you can use `html_escape` or the `h` alias:

```
<%= h @record.field %>
```